# java 2 different formula problems

Tags: java

I want to calculate the volume of a sphere using a Java program. So, I used

```
double result = 4/3*Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3);
```

This formula gives the wrong answers it seems.

Like Java program opt 4/3, but if I change it to

```
double result= Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3)*4/3;
```

it gives me the correct answer. Does any one know what is going on?

Comment: 1. formatting, 2. integer division (4/3) and 3. order of operation in java. Make sure these 3 things are checked.

Comment: I just fixed your format and most of the phrasing. For next time, please take your time to make your question presentable and readable. Use punctuation, upper case characters where neccessary and use the code tags, so it get's highlighted properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in the outcome is due to operator precedence. In Java, multiplication and division have equal precedence, and therefore are evaluated from left to right.

So, your first example is equivalent to

```
double result = (4/3)*Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3);
```

Here, 4/3 is a division of two integers, and in Java, in such cases integer division is performed, with outcome 1. To solve this, you have to explicitly make sure that one or both of the operands is a double:

```
double result = (4.0/3.0)*Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3);
```

Your second example, however, is equivalent to

```
double result = (Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3)*4)/3;
```

Here, the `Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3)*4` part is evaluated to a double, and thus we have no integer division anymore and you get the correct result.

Comment: This is the most elaborate answer. -> +1

Answer (score 5):

This has to do with the order in which casting occurs in Java (or C for that matter).

For the full details on operator precedence, see http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/.

In your first case, since the multiply and divide operators are computed from left to right, the first operation java interprets is 4/3.  Since both operands are integer, java computes an integer division, the result of which is 1.

In your second case, the first operation is the double multiply: (Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3)).  The second operation multiplies a double (Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3)) by an integer (4).  This is performed by casting 4 to a double and performing a double multiply.  Last, java has to divide a double (Math.PI*Math.pow(r,3)*4) by an integer (3), which java performs as a double division after casting 3 to a double.  This gives you the result you expect.

If you want to correct your first answer, cast 3 to double first:

```
 4/ (double)3
```

and you will get the result you expect.

Comment: Is there an advantage to `(double)3` instead of `3.0`?

Comment: None that I know of from a programmatic standpoint.  But I tend to use the explicit (double) casting notation because more than once I have been burnt by forgetting the '.' when changing the value of a constant later on.  E.g. I initially have a piece of code with something like double x = 3.14 / 2; and later I need to change my formula to, say, double x = 3.0 / 2; but I may inadvertently write double x = 3 / 2; especially with a long formula.  If the (double) is there, it stay there to enforce the casting no matter what the value is.  It's a safeguard I like to have.

Comment: I usually always use `.`, so I would do `x = 3.14 / 2.0` in the first place. And I think it is more readable than casting it explicitely.

Comment: as a compromise: write `3d`. This is shorter than either of `3.0` and `(double) 3` and still as explicit as casting (but without the cast).

Comment: Yes, if you are careful and awake, using 'd' or '.' for any number that you know ought to be casted to a double before the operation is perfectly fine.  However, for having made the mistake too many times, I simply no longer trust myself attaching anything to a number (like a 'd' or a '.') from fear of removing it inadvertently when updating that number.  When I write a (double) I know that I will only remove it intentionally. It's a writing style that reflects my own limitations really; it may too much of a safeguard for others who like more succinct code.

Answer (score 2):

`4/3` is a division between two `int`, so Java assumes that the result is also an `int` (in this case, this results in the value `1`). Change it to `4.0/3.0` and you'll be fine, because `4.0` and `3.0` are interpreted as `double` by Java.

```
double result = 4.0 / 3.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(r,3);
```